# Something similar to GenericDialog/ADM

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

I'm looking for something similar to GenericDialog used in ImageJ or Adobe Dialog Manager. The goal is to create a template of a dialog (number of fields, types etc - info that is needed, not how it is presented) and send it to view-class. This view may be Swing based GUI or simple console UI. User fills the fields and values are visible for the source of the dialog template. 
Is there some library for Java that implements this?
I know there is GenericDialog, but I'm not sure if I can use it in my project (as it is a part of ImageJ). What is more, I feel it's to 'heavy' for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [ImageJ2 project](http://developer.imagej.net/) provides almost exactly what you describe: a flexible mechanism for executing runnable operations (called *commands*) with typed input and output parameters.

You define the command's inputs and outputs by labeling them with the `@Parameter` annotation. ImageJ automatically takes care of filling in the inputs (typically by prompting the user for input using a dialog box), as well as displaying the outputs after the command has run.

How the inputs are harvested from the user depends on which (if any) user interface is associated with the ImageJ context. We have implemented full widget support for Swing, as well as proof-of-concept implementations in "pure" AWT (i.e., `java.awt` widgets), Apache Pivot and Eclipse SWT.

Some examples:

- [GradientImage.java](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-tutorials/blob/9e525b5defb1ebbafed806a976dd2746a8c3c868/simple-command/src/main/java/GradientImage.java#L20): A simple example command
- [ParameterTester.java](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/blob/c39e9ac3cb945b550dc438f3d330a6976ba15504/core/commands/debug/src/main/java/imagej/core/commands/debug/ParameterTester.java#L53): A command exercising many types of parameters

All of the code is BSD-2 licensed. The `ij-core` JAR containing the framework is ~334KB as of this writing. The `ij-ui-swing` JAR containing the Swing widgets is ~150KB, but it contains other things as well which could be stripped out (for comparison, the `ij-ui-pivot` JAR is only ~30KB).

All of that said, if you think ImageJ 1.x's `GenericDialog` is "too heavy" then you will very likely feel the same about ImageJ2's command framework (or really *any* other solution to this problem; I don't think it can get much "lighter" than `GenericDialog`). But in that case, perhaps the ImageJ2 implementation will give you some ideas on how to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Generic dialog in ImageJ extends java.awt.Component so doesn't this contradict your requirement that the template for the dialog be decoupled from the view?

Java's collections would allow you to encapsulate the info, types etc.

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap<String,Type> dialog = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<String,Type>;
```

where the key is the name of the field and the value is the type of the field.

To create a swing based dialog see

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html